# iOS initializing and returning a new object in a helper method

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, autorelease

I'm trying to understand this from a memory management point of view: In one class, I'm making a helper method that will create an NSDictionary object for me.

```
+(NSDictionary*) getTheDictionary{
    return [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"value", @"key", nil] autorelease];
}
```

From another class, I use the method.

```
NSDictionary* theDictionary = [HelperClass getTheDictionary];
```

Is it enough to just have "autorelease" in the return statement? Do I also need an autorelease on theDictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getTheDictionary` returns an autoreleased object, which means that the object is 
*valid* in the calling method, but not *owned* by the caller. Therefore the calling method
must not release or autorelease that object.

It will be released when the current autorelease pool ends, e.g. when program control
returns to the main event loop.

Comment: `getTheDictionary` doesn't really fit with standard naming conventions, either.

Comment: that was just made up for the sake of this question. I could have done "createADictionary" maybe